# How to trim out multiple time-points in an AVAsset (Swift)?

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avasset, avassetexportsession, avmutablecomposition

I am working on a video editor app, where based on some processing, I have an array of samples/time-points to remove from the video clip. For example,

timePoints = [0 8.2 15.5 20.6...]. //seconds

I would like to remove these specific frames from the video clip (i.e. AVAsset), which correspond to these time-points. From what I understand so far, you can use AVAssetExportSession to trim a specific time range (e.g. tstart to tend) but not multiple time-points (e.g. timePoints array above).

Hence, is there a way to export with multiple time-points discarded? i.e. the output video will merge together all clips, except the frames corresponding to those time-points to be discarded?

Would appreciate any help, Thanks!

Comment: What kind of data type is [0 8.2 15.5 20.6...]?

Comment: Hi El, it is an array of doubles: [Double]. Could always turn it into CMTime if necessary.